# How to setup WiFi hotspot in Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME?

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager

I've been trying to setup a hotspot from wired connection, but I can't seem to do it. Every tutorial I've found says to do it through "Edit connections", but I don't have that option since I have GNOME version.

When I try to do "Use as Hotspot" option in WiFi settings, the hotspot is started with the same name as my computer, but I can't connect to the hotspot from any device. How can I fix this? Thank you.